# ngModel for 3 dimensional array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Below is the 3 dimensional array returned from the API response which I need to show it up in the UI using angularjs.

```
"items": [[[12,13,14], [13,14,15]],[[13,14,15],[14,15,16]],[[14,15,16],[15,16,17]]]
```

For each and every element in the array, I have to bind these element to a ng-model of a textbox.

```
<input name="item" type="text" ng-model="???" placeholder="Enter a value" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had found the solution based on the suggestion by @karaxuna

```
<div ng-repeat="subItems in items">
    <div ng-repeat="subSubItems in subItems">
       <div ng-repeat="subSubSubItems in subSubItems">
          <input type="text" ng-model="subSubSubItems" />
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="subItems in items">
    <div ng-repeat="subSubItems in subItems">
        <input type="text" ng-model="subSubItems" ng-list />
    </div>
</div>
```